# How to test a string that only contains alphabets and numbers?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to test either a string contains only alphabets or numbers. Following statement should return false but it doesn't return. What am I doing wrong?

```
bool(re.match('[A-Z\d]', '2ae12'))
```

Comment: is it either alphabets or numbers?

Comment: You state 'test if a string contains only alphabets **and** numbers' but also 'following should return false'. Which is it? Letters AND digits or ALL numbers OR ALL digits?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the string method `isalnum()`, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: We probable don't know what *exactly* OP wants - only *English* letters, or the letters of *other* alphabets, too? 'isalnum()' considers as letters *all characters* defined in the Unicode character database as “Letter”, e. g. `á` or `Ť`. So it is mainly the comment (or the question) for OP - your answer may or may not satisfy his/her.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to return True if the string is either all digits or all letters, you can do:

```
for case in ('abcdefg','12345','2ae12'):
    print case, case.isalpha() or case.isdigit()
```

Prints:

```
abcdefg True
12345 True
2ae12 False
```

If you want the same logic with a regex, you would do:

```
import re
for case in ('abcdefg','12345','2ae12'):
    print case, bool(re.search(r'^(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d+)$', case))
```

Answer (score 1):

While not regex, you can use the very concise `str.isalnum()`:

```
s = "sdfsdfq34sd"
print(s.isalnum())
```

Output:

```
True
```

However, if you do want a pure regex solution:

```
import re
if re.findall('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', s):
    pass #string just contains letters and digits
```

Using a dataframe solution, courtesy of @Wen:

```
df.col1.apply(lambda x : x.isalnum())
df=pd.DataFrame( {'col1':["sdfsdfq34sd","sdfsdfq###34sd","sdfsdf!q34sd","sdfs‌​dfq34s@d"]})
```

Comment: how would you do this for data frame?I tried 

    df[df['attribute'].str.match.isalum()

and I keep getting an error

Comment: @Dan I am not familiar with dataframes, however, I retagged the question with both `pandas` and `dataframe`.

Comment: @Ajax1234 you can add this to your solution:-) .`df.col1.apply(lambda x : x.isalnum())`  Data input `df=pd.DataFrame( {'col1':["sdfsdfq34sd","sdfsdfq###34sd","sdfsdf!q34sd","sdfsdfq34s@d"]})`

Comment: @Wen thank you for mentioning that solution. I have included it in my answer.

Comment: @Ajax1234 your method is the key to solve this problem ~:-)

Comment: @Ajax1234 would you mind I change the apply function little bit ? Or you can do it , using `df.col1.str.isalnum()`  get rid of apply

Comment: @Wen please feel free to make any edits you would like :)

Comment: @Dan glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas answer: Consider this df

```
    col
0   2ae12
1   2912
2   da2ae12
3   %2ae12
4   #^%6f
5   &^$*
```

You can select the rows that contain only alphabets or numbers using

```
df[~df.col.str.contains('(\W+)')]
```

You get

```
    col
0   2ae12
1   2912
2   da2ae12
```

If you just want a boolean column, use

```
~df.col.str.contains('(\W+)')

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check is the string is made up of either alphabets or digits!

```
import re
bool(re.match('^[A-Za-z]+|\d+$', df['some_column'].str))
```

As dawg has suggested you can also use `isalpha` and `isdigit`,

```
df['some_column'].str.isalpha() or df['some_column'].str.isdigit()
```

Comment: how would you do the same test for a column of a data frame?

Comment: I've added the edits! if df is your dataframe and some_column is your column, you can use `df['some_column'].str`

Answer (score 0):

You regex is only matching one character, and I think the `\d` is being treated as an escaped D instead of the set of all integer characters.

If you really want to use a regex here's how I would do it;

```
def isalphanum(test_str):
    alphanum_re = re.compile(r"[0-9A-Z]+", re.I)
    return bool(alphanum_re.match(test_str)
```

Let's focus on the alphanum regex. I compiled it with a raw literal, indicated by the string with an 'r' next to it. This type of string won't escape certain characters when a slash is present, meaning `r"\n"` is interpreted as a slash and an N instead of a newline. This is helpful when using regexs, and certain text editors will even change the syntax highlighting of an R string to highlight features in the regex to help you out. The re.I flag ignores the case of the test string, so [A-Z] will match A through Z in either upper or lower case.

The simpler, Zen of Python solution involves invoking the `isalnum` method of the string;

```
test_str = "abc123"
test_str.isalnum()
```